# Why is my custom React-leaflet marker not displaying on my map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to make a custom marker icon for my leaflet component in react. I am defining an icon class and attempting make the iconURL the location of the PNG I use. The issue that I am running into is that the iconURL is only working for 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|abcdef&chf=a,s,ee00FFFF'.

I also tried using the directory of a PNG in my project, as well as a URL of an icon provided by google, for example 'https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Acable%3A'. These both however do not display the image correctly. Is it an issue with the specific PNGs that I am using? I tried overriding the default URL icon with L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.iconUrl however it just produced the same results. Below will also be an image of what the icon looks like when attempting to use the icons that do not work currently.

(EDIT: Including an image of my directory in case it helps)
[image]

[image: icon not displaying correctly]

```js
 function OutageIndicator({ outage }) {
   const LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
      options: {
          iconSize:     [38, 95],
          shadowSize:   [50, 64],
          iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
          shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
          popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
      }
    });

    L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.iconUrl = 'icons/marker.png';

    const streamingIcon = new LeafIcon({
      iconUrl:"icons/marker.png"
    });
    
  return !coords ? (
      "Loading"
    ) : (
      <Marker position={[coords.lat, coords.lng]} icon={streamingIcon}>
        <Popup className={outage.service_type}>
          {outage.service_type}: {outage.service_name}
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    );
}

function OutageMap() {
//a bunch of other lines of code

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={setReportIsOpenTrue}>Report Outage</button>
      <MapContainer center={[44, -85]} zoom={7} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

        {allOutages.map((mock) => (
          <OutageIndicator outage={mock} />
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}

export default OutageMap;
```

Comment: What do your DevTools console and network tab say when the browser tries to load these URL's?

Comment: marker.png:1 GET http://localhost:3000/icons/marker.png 404 (Not Found) 
Am I not using the correct directory address of the image? 

(I changed the image to marker.png will reflect it correctly in the post)

Comment: I will also include an image of my directory if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using React, there is probably a webpack build tool configured under the hood, with a file or url-loader.

In that case, you have to import or require your icon file, so that webpack knows that it must include it in your bundle:

```js
    const streamingIcon = new LeafIcon({
      iconUrl: require("./icons/marker.png")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vite and Typescript and the challenge with TS was not being able to use **import("./marker.svg")** since iconUrl expects a string and not a Promise < typeof import> so what I did was ***default import*** the icon, and the assignment in the class worked.

```
import marker from "./marker.svg"

const iconMarker = new L.Icon({
 iconUrl: marker,
 iconRetinaUrl: marker,
 iconSize: new L.Point(60, 75),
 className: "leaflet-div-icon",
})
```